# Linking 2 mongoose schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schemas, a `Team` and a `Match`. I want to use the `Team Schema` to identify the Teams in the `Match Schema`. So far, here is my Team and Match JS files. I want to link the Team Schema to my Match Schema so that I can identify the home or away team simply, and so that I am storing in the Match Schema an actual Team object.

This way I can refer to the home team for example as `Match.Teams.home.name = England` (this is just an example of course)

Team.js

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var validatePresenceOf = function(value){
  return value && value.length; 
};

var getId = function(){
  return new Date().getTime();
};

/**
  * The Team schema. we will use timestamp as the unique key for each team
  */
var Team = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'name' : { type : String,
              validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
              index : { unique : true }
            }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

And here is what I am trying to do with Match.js

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TeamSchema = require('mongoose').model('Team');

var validatePresenceOf = function(value){
  return value && value.length; 
};

var toLower = function(string){
  return string.toLowerCase();
};

var getId = function(){
  return new Date().getTime();
};

/**
  * The Match schema. Use timestamp as the unique key for each Match
  */
var Match = new Schema({
  'key' : {
    unique : true,
    type : Number,
    default: getId
  },
  'hometeam' : TeamSchema,
  'awayteam' : TeamSchema
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', Match);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution: Use the actual schema, rather than a model that uses the schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

To

```
module.exports = {
    model: mongoose.model('Team', Team),
    schema: Team
};
```

and then `var definition = require('path/to/js');` that, and use `definition.schema` instead of a model directly

Comment: I have changed the Team exports as you said to. In the Match.js file I now have `var definition = require('Team.js');` and I am storing `hometeam` as `definition.schema` but I get the error that `cannot find module Team.js`, any idea?

Comment: Sorry to comment again, but I fixed this by putting the full path and now get `TypeError: Undefined type at `hometeam` and asking me if I am nesting schemas

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to nest schemas.

Try Population in Mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Schema.Types.ObjectId` in Match.js :

> `hometeam: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
>   awayteam: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }`